# Cfscript and dynamic values

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I have a custom class written in java which works fine if I use hard coded data but I would like to get the data from the URL instead of hard coded

```
<cfscript>
   scraper = createObject("java", "AccessOS2Scraper");
   foo     = scraper.getText( "web", "2014", "https://access.acme.com/AsrDisplay.do?asrno=1432310020&icsc=SW11");
</cfscript>
```

My syntax is, `user = web`, `passwd = 2014` and `url = https://....`

So I would like to call my page something like that

http://myserver.domain.com/mytest.cfm?user=web&passwd=2014=url=https://https://access.acme.com/AsrDisplay.do?..

How can I access these elements inside the cfscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may reference the variables via the `URL` scope in CF.  You may want to wrap the values with `JavaCast()` and cast the value into the right type, just in case.

Comment: Thanks the problem was not the url scope but cast. Once I casted the values to a string it worked, basic cfset threw error's